# Burninate [continous-integration]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

IMHO we should burninate [continous-integration](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continous-integration) (typo) to prevent its proliferation, correct one is [continuous-integration](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration)

It only covers one (on-hold) question presently.

Comment: Wouldn't people with enough reputation have the privilege to edit/rename/merge/combine tags eventually?

Comment: Yep, but the op itself needs to be tracked/cordinated - this is the tracking method, at least on SO, from where I copied the tags. Also - we don't have those high-rep users on this site yet :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Burnination requests are not necessary when the tag is an obvious misspelling and the number of questions is small. Simply edit the question to fix the tag, and at night an automated clean-up script will delete the tag completely.
Should it happen that a misspelled tag is used on a lot of questions, then flag one of the questions for *Moderator attention*. Moderators can fix the tag without flooding the front page with a bunch of edited questions (and pushing off actual new content).

Someone has fixed the tag you mentioned in your question, so normally by tomorrow the tag should be completely gone.

Related reading on Meta Stack Overflow (we might eventually copy that content to this Meta): [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

Comment: One correction: If you are renaming a large number of tags, don't start editing them one at a time. 'Flag' one of the posts for Moderator attention, and they can correct the error without *bumping* a bunch of posts to the 'activiity' page unnecessarily.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Edited to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: @Stijn Yup, typo tag is gone now. Thx.

Comment: @RobertCartaino As per the current status of this question (the tag is gone ...), should this question be retagged then with something like "completed"? I mean such red tag or something only a mod can use I believe.

Answer (score 6):

If possible to combine/merge all the different misspellings and permutations on the word "continuous" (of which there are many) into a single tag, it would make the OCD users happy, including myself.

If you see a single misspelled tag, you can edit it yourself. But if the misspelling has already propagated beyond a few, you can 'flag' it for Moderator attention to fix it.

Comment: This *might* be achievable using tag synonyms, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: @DanCornilescu No, tag synonyms are intended to link two completely separate words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). Once you get out of private beta, it becomes more difficult to inadvertently create new tags, so for simple misspellings, text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage.

Comment: @RobertCartaino ACK.

Comment: @RobertCartaino is it really necessary to edit discussion items to turn my lack of knowledge into knowledge I didn't know? :/

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, Stack Exchange is wiki-style collaborative system. You left an (incomplete) thought that stated "I don't know how this works, but..." so I filled it out. I did not change the intention of what you wrote, but made the information complete and correct. Not only is that appropriate, but it's the entire *purpose* of having a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Right, I do understand. Guess that is the reason why I hate participating in SE sites so much. It doesn't take into account the human element. Things like hurt feelings, the extrinsic motivation that suddenly doesn't just dry up but can actually be taken away (if it would be a game, people would scream and shout), assumptions and expectations that are turned to be incorrect (like meta is discussion, and my opinion matters, it even has my name on it), etc.

Comment: @Evgeny If you hate participating so much, why do you continue? (rhetorical question; that's for you to decide) Before I came to Stack Exchange, I had a good deal of experience copy editing and fact checking. Most people just thanked me for making them look good. But for the 0.1% who feel like "DON'T TOUCH MY STUFF!", then a site whose very mission ls to curate a live, wiki-based collaboration is probably not for them; they're better off starting their own blog or something. No slight or hurt feelings were intended; take care.